# Let Y denote the largest number obtained in n independent rolls of a fair die, where n is a positive integer . What is the probability mass function?

Tags: probability

y = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

My first try is $(1/6)*(y/6)^{n-1}$ , but this doesn’t work, should I consider the order?

How to find the formula for pmf and cdf?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) whenever you type a formula on this site. It’s pretty easy. You just enclose your formulae into the $ signs, for the most part.